# ArrayAdapter.getItem(position) gets wrong items after scrolling

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter

I have this problem with the following code: 
 when I instantiate the Adapter with my list of objects, the order of the list is still fine, and so are the first seven visible rows. But as soon as I scroll down the list, and the `convertView`s are recycled, I get some repeating titles/subtitles (eg. the eighth row has the title of the second row, the ninth of the fourth row, always the same pattern). Since some rows that are visible have the same title/subtitle, the bug cannot be with recycling the view.

```
public RomantikObjectAdapter(Context context, List<RomantikObject> items) {
    super(context, R.layout.listitem_object, items);
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    mContext = context;
}

static class ViewHolder {
    TextView title;
    TextView subtitle;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listitem_object, parent, false);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
        holder.subtitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.subtitle);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    RomantikObject item = getItem(position);

    holder.title.setText(item.getTitle());
    holder.subtitle.setText(item.getSubtitle());

    return convertView;
}
```

Everything seems to work fine, except `getItem(position)`. I tried to have the `items` in a field in the class, so I can do `items.get(position)`. But I get exactly the same wrong order.

Perhaps the list is re-ordered without my knowledge? How can I detect or avoid this?

Comment: How are you populating the list that gets passed to the adapter? Note that since you're passing a `List`, `ArrayAdapter` doesn't make a deep copy of it, and if you're modifying the underlying list yourself, it will be also visible in the adapter view.

Comment: Please define a full code of Adapter so we are able to find the Exact coding of getItem method also.

Comment: @laalto I have a few lists that work the same way in my app, but only this instance has this ordering problem. The `list` is generaded by the ORM (http://www.activeandroid.com/)

Comment: @RajanBhavsar This is the basically whole code of the adapter. The `getItem()` method is provided by the `ArrayAdapter`. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#getItem(int)

Comment: Try to Use List  items object for example list_items.get(position) in place of getItem(Position).

Comment: @RajanBhavsar I tried that, and even with `list_items = ImmutableList.copyOf(items)` the order is changed, even though initially `list_items` order is right?! I don't know what is going on...

Comment: May i Know What is the Usage of that code in your Project? So I give you an alternate solution for that also.

Answer (score 0):

Copy this Code And Run

```
 List<RomantikObject> thisArray;
String value1,value2;
public RomantikObjectAdapter(Context context, List<RomantikObject> items) {
    super(context, R.layout.listitem_object, items);
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    mContext = context;
    this.thisArray=item;
}

static class ViewHolder {
    TextView title;
    TextView subtitle;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listitem_object, parent, false);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
        holder.subtitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.subtitle);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    value1 = items.get(position).getTitle();
        value2 = items.get(position).getSubtitle();


    holder.title.setText(value1);
    holder.subtitle.setText(value2);

    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: Tried it, does not fix the problem. :(

Comment: well did to try using without view holder ?

Comment: Yes, I did. When I encountered this bug, I added the `ViewHolder` since I thought that could fix it (but of course it did not).

Comment: and did u check your values ? sure they are different

Comment: I checked everything, the problem seems to be that `getItem(position)` returns an item from another position, as if the list is re-ordered deterministically.

Comment: u can make an custom arraylist of your getter setter class then u can inflate it

Comment: I just tried it, and even when I use `this.thisArray = ImmutableList.copyOf(items);` the order is changed ?!